# How to filter an array of strings in ksh

Tags: linux, shell, perl, ksh

I want to remove the IP's as defined in "bb"  array from "aa" array so the IP's **255.0.0.0** and **255.255.255.0** will be removed from the list in **aa** array.

When I run my ksh code and later print the array aa, I see that the IP - **255.255.255.0** was not deleted?

What's wrong in my syntax?

```
   echo ${aa[*]}
   45.32.3.5 255.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 19.23.2.12


   echo ${bb[*]}
   255.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

ksh program:

```
  for run in  ${bb[*]}
  do
   for ((i=0; i<${#aa[@]}; i++)); do
   [[ ${aa[i]} == $run ]] && unset aa[i]
   done
  done
```

test:

```
 echo ${aa[*]}
   45.32.3.5 255.255.255.0 19.23.2.12
```

**NOTE:** 255.255.255.0 should be deleted from the above list.

Comment: @sim maybe it will be better to transfer my question to stackoverflow

Comment: your code works for me. What is the value of `IFS` in your environment?

Comment: each IP is separately IP as the following 
 aa[1]=45.32.3.5
 aa[2]=255.0.0.0
 aa[3]=255.255.255.0
 aa[4]=19.23.2.12
 bb[1]=255.0.0.0
 bb[2]=255.255.255.0

Comment: can you try `for run in  "${bb[@]}"` instead of `for run in  ${bb[*]}` and see?

Comment: I run it and - I get the same problem

Comment: ok. is each element of `bb`separately defined? what does `echo "${#bb[@]}"` give?

Comment: echo "${#bb[@]}" 2   ( gives 2 )

Comment: interesting. I am unable to reproduce your issue. We may be on different versions of ksh. You may want to add your ksh version to the question. All the best.

Comment: Code works on Fedora 17 with the packaged ksh93. Try to put a minimal working example (including the definition of your arrays) into a script file and call it like `ksh file.sh`. Also I would use an associative array instead of the inner for loop.

Comment: @1_CR, I've updated my answer with a analysis of the original code.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, I read your excellent before and +1ed it. The points you added subsequently make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your code does not work for the presented inputs. It does on my system under ksh.

But your original code has a problem: the conditional part `i<${#aa[@]}` is fragile - since `${#aa[@]}`, i.e. the array size is decremented after each `unset` - but the following array elements are not automatically shifted to the left. For your example

```
45.32.3.5 255.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 19.23.2.12
```

this does not make a difference - but it would make a difference for - say:

```
45.32.3.5 255.0.0.0 19.23.2.12 255.255.255.0
```

I improved the code with respect to that issue (note the assignment before loop entry). I also eliminated an inner loop (using an associative array) which improves the runtime from quadratic to linear:

```
$ cat x.sh
```

outputs it:

```
aa=(45.32.3.5 255.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 19.23.2.12)
bb=([255.0.0.0]=1 [255.255.255.0]=1)

print Size of input ${#aa[*]}
print Size of exclude list ${#bb[*]}

n=${#aa[*]}
for ((i=0; i<$n; ++i))
do
  if [[ ${bb[${aa[i]}]} ]]
  then
    print Removing element with index $i: ${aa[i]}
    unset aa[i];
  fi
  print New size of input ${#aa[*]}
done

print Resulting size of input ${#aa[*]}
print Resulting elements ${aa[*]}

for ((i=0; i<$n; ++i))
do
  print Index $i, Value 'a['$i']'=${aa[$i]}
done
```

It produces following output on Fedora 17:

```
$ ksh x.sh
Size of input 4
Size of exclude list 2
New size of input 4
Removing element with index 1: 255.0.0.0
New size of input 3
Removing element with index 2: 255.255.255.0
New size of input 2
New size of input 2
Resulting size of input 2
Resulting elements 45.32.3.5 19.23.2.12
Index 0, Value a[0]=45.32.3.5
Index 1, Value a[1]=
Index 2, Value a[2]=
Index 3, Value a[3]=19.23.2.12
```